# Bootstrap 3: nested row has 0 height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

My markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>    
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row"> <!-- this has 0 height -->
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What can be the reason that the nested row has correct width, 0 height and can't have a `margin-bottom`, no matter what contain its colums?

Interesting thing, when I positioned absolutely a pseudoelement `::after` for this row, it resolves correctly sizes like `top: 50%` but only if the problematic row has `position: static` and not when it has `position: relative`.

Comment: They actually have a height of 1px. [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/N6eICmOyRP). Here it also can have a margin-bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/phn3Lae6/1

When you remove `position: absolute` from `::after` pseudoelement, row behaves normally.

Since ::before and ::after pseudoelements are an important part of Bootstrap grid, probably the best solution here is to not mess around with them, but to create a separate element inside the grid element to be a pseudoelement parent, for example like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="pseudoelement-parent">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.pseudoelement-parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The row's height might be collapsing due to its floated children? Try adding a clearfix to clear the row of its children's floats:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
```

I'm not entirely sure without seeing any of your own CSS that could be also causing issues, but the above might resolve the issue. FYI - The `clearfix` class ships with BootStrap.

Here's a good read and other information on clearfix: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: Clearfix changed nothing. There's no other CSS which could affect layout. Disabling `float: left` on children gives appropriate height to row but obviously breaks the grid.

Comment: To be clear, I don't need a workaround because I can figure out one on my own, I would just like to know what happens here and what is a *correct* solution to make the .row behave appropriately.

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/pucpjqjt/](https://jsfiddle.net/pucpjqjt/) the two nested columns have content in them and the row has a height... [https://jsfiddle.net/8vqLwse3/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/8vqLwse3/1/) inspecting the row in this without any content shows that the row has a height of 1px... I can't replicate what you're seeing I'm afraid? @Senthe

Comment: Yeah, I know it should work and something specific to my app had to happen, maybe there's some compilation error, I don't know. I'll investigate this. For now I resolved the problem with `float: none; display: inline-block;` on children.

Comment: Okay I reproduced the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/phn3Lae6/1/
When you remove `position: absolute` from `::after`, row behaves normally. Moral: don't mess around with Bootstrap grid pseudoelements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to copy bootstrap's columns and I was also wondering why my row's height is 0. It turned out that `display: table;`, `content: " ";` and `clear: both;` are all important for the row's height.

I hope this helps someone.